# What is equivalent for Autosize in Listbox control of winforms?

Tags: winforms

I have a ListBox control.What I want is that it will expand as an when the screen size is maximized.
Which proeprty to set for that?

For label it is Autosize = true.

But what it is for Listbox control?

Comment: [Manage WinForm controls using the Anchor and Dock properties](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/6165908)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use the `Dock` property to `Fill` to fill the list box to the container, or use the `Anchor` property to sides you want the list box to expand (if you want the list box to expand to the right, enable the anchor to `Left`, `Top`, `Right`).